# Leetcode - Find First and Last Position of Element in Sorted Array (runtime improvement)

Tags: python, arrays, binary-search

I would like to get some advice on how I can improve my code runtime. Here is a solution for the Leetcode task "Find First and Last Position of Element in Sorted Array".

*"Given an array of integers nums sorted in non-decreasing order, find the starting and ending position of a given target value.

If target is not found in the array, return [-1, -1].

You must write an algorithm with O(log n) runtime complexity.

Example 1:

Input: nums = [5,7,7,8,8,10], target = 8
Output: [3,4]"*

Here is an algorithm (Python):

#We search for the first target value using a normal binary search. "Left"/"right" were added as #indexes of target values boundaries [left, right] (if we have several target values).

```
    left = -1 
    right = -1
    pointer = 0 # I added "pointer" to use it for "while" loops 
    low = 0
    high = len(nums)-1
    while low <= high:
        mid = (high + low)/2
        guess = nums[mid]
        if guess == target:

            #check the left boundary first with the "while" loop

            pointer = mid
            while pointer >= 0 and nums[pointer] == target:
                left = pointer
                pointer -= 1

            #check the right boundary with the "while" loop

            pointer = mid
            while pointer <= len(nums)-1 and nums[pointer] == target:
                right = pointer
                pointer += 1

            return [left,right]

        elif guess > target:
            high = mid-1

        else:
            low = mid + 1

    return [left,right]
```

The execution time takes between 47 and 62 ms. Could you suggest what could be improved here? Especially - how to find the sequence of target values more efficiently. Thanks

Comment: The worst case scenario is `O(n)`. ie when all the array is the same as the target, then you have to go through everything and return the first and loast index `[0,n]`. The best case scenario is when you have only one value in the array same as target; `O(log(n))` using binary search. You should consider having a linear search from the point of equalness left +right AFTER the binary search. not linear search INSIDE binary search. which will give you `O(max(log(n), m))` where `m` is the number of times the target is repeated

Comment: At the same time, if you are dealing with integers, you can optimize the code such that the complexity is O(2log(n)) which is O(log(n)) as 2 is a constant. ie run binary search twice. first for a number greater than the digit. eg `binary_search(nums, 8+0.1)` to get the upper index, and with 8-0.1 to get the lower index.

Comment: That is very interesting that you suggested using target+0.1! I wanted to try target-1 and target+1 but it doesn't work since we simply may not have these numbers in the list.

Comment: Your list has integers. Minus and plus 0.1 will definitely work. That is because you are not looking for the number that is equal to it but rather the two numbers that contain the target

Answer (score 0):

In your approach, when `guess == target`, you are then traversing the list in a linear fashion to find the start and end index of the target. This will result in O(n) time complexity.

However, you can optimize it by instead of traversing the list linearly (when the target is found), traverse the left and right part of the list again in a binary search fashion. This will result in O(log n) space complexity overall.

```
def binary_search(target: int, start: int, end: int, search_left: bool):
    while start <= end:
        mid = (start + end) // 2
        if nums[mid] == target: # found the target
            if search_left:  # i.e., when we want to search the first index
                # if the element just before the mid is not target,
                # we have found the left most index (bound by start idx)
                if mid == 0 or nums[mid - 1] != target:
                    return mid
                # if nums[mid-1] == target, then there are more target elements to the left
                # then binary search from 'start' to 'mid-1'
                end = mid - 1
            else:  # i.e., when we want to search the last index
                # if the element just after the mid is not target,
                # we have found the right most index (bound by end idx)
                if mid == len(nums) - 1 or nums[mid + 1] != target:
                    return mid
                # if nums[mid+1] == target, then there are more target elements to the right
                # then binary search from 'mid+1' to 'end'
                start = mid + 1
        elif nums[mid] > target:
            end = mid - 1
        else:
            start = mid + 1
    return -1


nums = [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 10, 12]
left = binary_search(8, 0, len(nums) - 1, True)
if left == -1:
    right = -1
else:
    right = binary_search(8, 0, len(nums) - 1, False)
print([left, right])
```

Output

```
[0, 4]
```

Comment: Good day, and thanks for your help! Am I correct,  if we are using the O(n) algorithm inside the O(Log(n)) - we lose log(n) efficiency?  Do you think that we can use just 0 instead of "start" for "if mid == start or nums[mid - 1] != target:" cause as it is always 0 for List? I like the approach, you made a generic function that allows us to find both indexes in O(log(n))

Comment: Yes, if have ```O(n)``` complexity loop inside ```O(log n)``` block, then the final complexity would be ```O(n log n)```. You make a good point of using ```0``` instead of ```start``` for ```if mid == start``` because if the ```nums[mid] == target``` and if ```mid == 0```, that would become the left index. Going further, we can also replace ```end``` with ```len(nums) - 1``` for  ```if mid == end or nums[mid + 1] != target:```. I will edit the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A binary search is a good approach initially. If the target is found, just scan back and forth from the index value returned from your binary search function to find the limits.

A potential performance improvement can be made to the binary search function by carrying out an early check to determine if the target value can possibly be in the source list.

```
class Solution:
    def bsearch(self, slist: list[int], item: int) -> int:
        if slist:
            if item < slist[0] or item > slist[-1]:
                return -1
            hi = len(slist) - 1
            lo = 0
            while lo <= hi:
                m = lo + (hi - lo) // 2
                mv = slist[m]
                if mv == item:
                    return m
                if mv < item:
                    lo = m + 1
                else:
                    hi = m - 1
        return -1
    
    def searchRange(self, nums: list[int], target: int) -> list[int]:
        i = self.bsearch(nums, target)
        if i < 0:
            return [-1, -1]
        s = e = i
        while s > 0 and nums[s-1] == target:
            s -= 1
        m = len(nums) - 1
        while e < m and nums[e+1] == target:
            e += 1
        return [s, e]
```

Comment: Thanks for a hint! You also divided it into 2 functions in comparison with my solution. Did I understand correctly that in searchRange() function we also have an O(n) complexity?

Comment: Why do we need to check "if slist:" in bsearch func?

Comment: @Ilia Yes you do need to check it. If you don't and you then reference list[0] you'll get an IndexError exception. If slist is is *falsey* then the item being searched for cannot possibly exist

Comment: That is interesting! Thank you! I didn't know we had to check that the list existed (for operations with list[0] or list[-1]). I've also checked the situation with exception - indeed, it works only with "if slist:" statement